# Arduino Uno - Firmata/Serial Communication in Visual Studio C++

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, c++, communication, visualstudio

I need to pass `std::vector <double>` values from a C++ console program (written in Visual Studio 2015) running on a PC to Arduino in real-time using USB serial communication. Can anyone of you give any advice on how to implement Firmata or something similar into a C++ console application?

I googled everywhere and could not find a decent example for C++. Almost everything can be computed in console app, Arduino needs to work only with LCD display and beside that it can have StandardFirmata uploaded.

Comment: If you are willing to use python to write a simple scripts you can use Telemetry ([See on github](https://github.com/Overdrivr/Telemetry)) to exchange the data to [Pytelemetry](https://github.com/Overdrivr/pytelemetry). Using a technique called `indexing` you can send arrays and sparse arrays. The C implementation of the protocol doesn't support it out of the box but it's 2 lines of code to add to your embedded application. Let me know (I am the author)

Comment: Do you have an upst date on this issue?  I looking to compile the FIrmata test app in VIsual Studio 2017 in C++